# MS Access - Query - LIKE with Escape characters not working

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to search for in an MS Access Query for entries that contain (1), (2), etc. with zero or more characters before AND after. However, when I try the query, it returns no entries. Below is the like portion of my SQL:

```
Like '%[(]1-9[)]%'
```

I'm sorry but I cannot provide the rest of the SQL code. I know that the joining is working properly, I'm just having trouble with this portion.

Thanks

Comment: The "escape" character is the bracket "[", the wildcard character is the asterisk "*" (in Access) or the percent sign "%" in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcard character in MS Access is `'*'`, not `'%'`.

So, try this:

```
Like '*([1-9])*'
```